# MySQL date select query doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL database, I have many records with date in format like 08/31/2017 which is saved as "text" in MySQL column.

In my html & php script, I am using all these dates as drop down select in html by using the following script which works fine and I am saving it in

```
<select name='day'>
```

and in my php script, I am using the following to select date if not set initially..

```
$day = isset($_GET['day']) ? $_GET['day']:'08/31/2017';
```

In mysql query, I am using the following and query is not working..

```
 $result=$dbconnect->query("SELECT * FROM testtable where (`HR` = $hr and `DAY` = $day) ORDER BY `HR` DESC");
```

Please help what is not right..my script works fine if I dont use date in queries..

Comment: 1) you need to quote the $day using your current query building method.  BUT 2) you really should be escaping any insecure input.

Comment: **1st :** save the  date as a date not as a text

Comment: @trex005 parameter binding > escaping

Comment: 1st of all learn prepared statements.

Comment: 1.save dates as `date` not text, bad practice.2.use prepared statements to prevent from SQL Injection

Comment: @Syed where do you get $hr, i.e. what does the PHP code look like that assigns a value to that variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding quotation marks(`'`) around the `$day` variable in your query since it is a string value,

Do like below:-

```
$result=$dbconnect->query("SELECT * FROM testtable where (`HR` = $hr and `DAY` = '$day') ORDER BY `HR` DESC");
```

Comment: try to provide an useful answer supported with some sort of code, not just statements.

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype to `date` for date entries in MySQL..
Then in your PHP code, do following:

```
$date1 = date_create($_GET['day']);

$date = date_format($date1, 'm/d/Y');
```

And then pass it to your query.

**And using prepared statements is highly recommended**

Answer (score 0):

**Try this query**

```
SELECT * FROM testtable where (`HR` = $hr and `DAY` = DATE('$day')) ORDER BY `HR` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with the SQL query, such that $hr and $day need to be enclosed by escaped quotes.

Note, you should not trust user-supplied data. One way to deal with such data is to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection, but one should carefully consider their usage as per the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

> Using a prepared statement is not always the most efficient way of
>   executing a statement. A prepared statement executed only once causes
>   more client-server round-trips than a non-prepared statement.

Nonetheless, per [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28with_Parameterized_Queries.29):

> In rare circumstances, prepared statements can harm performance. When
>   confronted with this situation, it is best to either a) strongly
>   validate all data or b) escape all user supplied input using an
>   escaping routine specific to your database vendor as described below,
>   rather than using a prepared statement.

So, you should validate the data and then, at a minimum, use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), as follows:

```
<?php
$hr = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['hr']);
$day = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['day']);
```

Then, escape the quotes encompassing variables $hr and $day in the query, as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `date_hr` WHERE (HR=\"$hr\" and date=\"$day\") ORDER BY HR DESC";

$result = $dbconnect->query( $sql );
```